# Increase memory for grails app

Tags: grails

my grails app creates many message driven beans. How can I increase the memory to prevent perm gem? My tomcat has Free memory: 886.10 MB Total memory: 1237.18 MB Max memory: 8888.93 MB. But the app's memory is seperate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the permgen maximum allocation in the tomcat config to be something like -XX:MaxPermSize=256M.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a war in a stand-alone app server, set JAVA_OPTS, tomcat pick it up. If you're running with grails run-app, set GRAILS_OPTS instead to affect it.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

Comment: in the terminal, before you run "grails run-app"